# Aclaración sobre colocar <script> en Html

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Quiero hacer un input "autocomplete" aquí:

```html
<div id="wrap-search">
            <div class="search">
                <h2>Busca Destinos</h2>
                <input id="form-autocomplete" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="      Alaska, Nueva Zelanda, California...">
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Nunca he usado jQuery pero he visto en un articulo en un blog que simplemente usando Bootstrap y jQuery con poner este código ya debería funcionar:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#idLocalNames', function () {
    var list = [
        "Test",
        "Test 2",
        "Test 4",
        "Example 1",
       "Example 2"
            ];
    $(this).autocomplete({
        //source take a list of data
        source: list,
        minLength: 1//min = 2 characters
    });
});
```

Sin embargo no funciona nada, creo que es porque no tengo claro como colocar los CDN, ahora mismo lo tengo así:

```
al final del body:

<script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 y arriba

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
</head>
```

He añadido sobre eso los "scripts" de jQuery con la misma estrategia que los de Bootstrap, pero no funciona. De hecho, acaso los de Bootstrap no llevan ya "integrado" jQuery? Que links exactamente tengo que hacer referencia para que esto funcione?

Comment: Primero que nada, Bootstrap no incluye jQuery de forma nativa, son CDNs diferentes y por lo tanto separados, sólo es necesario si se va a hacer uso de `bootstrap.js`. Segundo, te falta hacer uso de jQuery UI, que es una biblioteca para el framework jQuery. Puedes ver su CDN [aquí](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que pasa es que Jquery viene una versión mínima, no completa, por lo cual es mejor reemplazar por la versión completa del mismo, adicional también para el autocomplete debes usar Jquery-UI ejemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Mi primer autocomplete</h1>
    <div id="wrap-search">
      <div class="search">
        <h2>Busca Destinos</h2>
        <input id="form-autocomplete" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="test, example">

      </div>
    </div>

<!-- JQUERY 1.12.4 COMPLETO -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <!-- SCRIPTS DE BOOTSTRAP -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- CSS Y JS DE JQUERY-UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
var list = [
        "Test",
        "Test 2",
        "Test 4",
        "Example 1",
       "Example 2"
            ];
    $("#form-autocomplete").autocomplete({
        //source take a list of data
        source: list,
        minLength: 1//min = 2 characters
    });
</script>
```

Te puedes fijar como cargo por defecto las librerías de bootstrap, pero la diferencia que coloco también jquery completo y jquery-ui para que funcione el autocomplete.

Referencias:

[Ejemplo Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

[Autocomplete Jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Espero te sirva y te ayude..suerte..!!